# How to place long select box text below a custom arrow with css only

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, background

I am designing a custom arrow (using background image) for a group of select boxes.

Problem is that each select box should be very short in width and therefore if the text is longer than this width it appears over the background arrow.
I need to find a way to display the background image over the text.

The other problem is that there are about 500 such select boxes and I do not wish to add a span layer in the HTML code for each of those boxes to accomplish the goal.

Therefore I am looking for a CSS solution only. JS would not work either.

Here is the CSS:

```
.dropdown{
    width:57px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:3px 4px 4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.dropdown select{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    padding: 1px 0 0 5px;
    width:145%;
    background: url(http://i57.tinypic.com/nnmgpy_th.png) no-repeat right;
background-position: 55%;
    }
```

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pazzesco/r6c9zcpc/

Any comments or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just increasing the right padding on your `.dropdown` selector to say 10px? 
`padding:3px 10px 4px;` should make sure your text never overlaps over the arrow.

Or do you actually want the text to display *behind* the arrow (which won't work as you've got the arrow as a background image)? :)

I hope I haven't misunderstood the question!

Cheers
Ines

Comment: hi Ines, padding won't work since I am intentionally hiding the default select box arrow. What I need is to display/hide/cut the text so that the background image is on top.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase padding-right values by 30px.

**.dropdown select{ padding: 1px 30px 0 5px; }**

Result: This will clip the text; 30px from right side.

JSFiddle Here: `[http://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/Lq7hosrd/2/]`

Comment: hi vishnu, padding won't work since I am intentionally hiding the default select box arrow. What I need is to display/hide/cut the text so that the background image is on top.

Comment: Hi @BradG, have you looked at the jsfiddle i posted?. Not the result you are looking for?

Comment: thank you for the jsfiddle, I checked it but changing the padding moves the default arrow over the background image, something that I do not want. What I need is to hide or crop the text below this background image.

Comment: Yeah Welcome! You must change the padding-right value of **.dropdown select{}**, and not the **.dropdown{}**. Hope you can fix as i did.